# Athena Unnesting mixed types

Tags: amazon-athena, amazon-cloudtrail

I normally unnest like so :

```
SELECT h.field1, rp.p.key1, rp.p.key2
FROM
  mytable h
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(h.field2) rp (p)
```

However, I am now looking at querying AWS CloudTrail data.
Here the field that I want to unnest varies...

Sometimes it's a single object:

> {"principal":{"dataLakePrincipalIdentifier":"arn:aws:iam::......

Other times it contains a wrapper object around an array of objects

> {"entries":[{"id":"0","principal":{"dataLakePrincipalIdentifier":"arn:aws:iam::.........

The only way that I can currently think of to tackle this, is to create 2 separate queries; one to unpack the singletons, another to unpack the array entries - and then union the two results together.

I'd be grateful if anyone knows of a more efficient approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by checking on the existence of a specific key inside the object, and do the following:

1. If the key is absent, this is definitely a single object of type (`map(varchar, json)`. Convert it to look like a `map(varchar, array(json)`.
2. If the key is present, leave it as is.

Let's say, we check on the existence of key `entries`:

```
with data as (
  select CAST(json_parse(your_json_string) AS MAP(VARCHAR, json )) as p
  from mydataset.mytable
)

select cast(json_extract(j, '$.principle') as map(varchar, integer)) as record from (
     select 
     if(
       cardinality(filter(map_keys(p), x -> x = 'entries')) = 1, 
       p,
       MAP(ARRAY['entries'], array[cast(array[p] as json)])
     ) as x from data2
), unnest(cast(x['entries'] as array(json))) as z(j)
```

Please note this part, specifically:

```
if(
  cardinality(filter(map_keys(p), x -> x = 'entries')) = 1, 
  p,
  MAP(ARRAY['entries'], array[cast(array[p] as json)])
)
```

It does the job of converting a single object to look like a regular `map(varchar, array(json))` which makes everything look alike.

Comment: Khan, apologies for the late response ! But thank you, this is great, and with excellent explanations :)